# How to wrap text in Dispform.aspx for all items in a list

Tags: 2013, list, edit-form, newform, dispform

Does anybody know of a way to wrap text column headers/questions on a SharePoint 2013 list?

I had posted a question on here a few days back about how to do this on `Newform.aspx`. I have since managed this with the help of an answer from my question on here but it doesn't apply to `Dispform.aspx`. I have tried viewing a list item so it opens as a `dispform.aspx` and then editing the page, adding a script editor and inserting the same code used for `newform.aspx` but this doesn't seem to work.

The code that was used in newform.aspx is below, it also works for editform.aspx as well.

```
.ms-formlabel {
    width: 400px;
}
.ms-formlabel nobr {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Does anyone how to make this work for `dispform.aspx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `DispForm.aspx` uses the class `ms-standardheader`, so you'd need to add

```
.ms-standardheader {
    width: 400px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

to your css.